# Add float or align selector for CCK image fields

Tags: entities

I'd like to add a float/align drop-down selector for each CCK image field in my content items. Then, that image would float/align itself on either side of the content (left or right), depending on whether "left" or "right" was selected from the drop-down. Ideally, this drop-down would be in the same general area as the ALT and Title fields are in the admin view of the content item.

Does anyone know if this is possible without custom programming?

Answer (score 0):

Look into the Display Suite Module: http://drupal.org/project/ds

It is designed to give you more control of the display of your content from the Admin UI. There are links to detailed screencasts on the project page. You'll see versions for both D6 and D7.

I don't know if you get those options on the 'add new content' page, but it wouldn't surprise me if you did.

Comment: I checked out DS (actually already had it installed), but I didn't see any settings that would add a float/align option to all images.